# Async websocket Python

Tags: python, websocket, asyncio

Пишу асинхронный модуль отправки сообщений по WS. Сообщения для отправки должны формироваться отдельно от самого Вебсокета. Ничего другого, кроме как Asyncio.Queue() не придумал (может подскажите более удобный метод).
На данный момент есть код:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import websockets


class EchoWebsocket:
    def __await__(self):
        return self._async_init().__await__()

    async def _async_init(self):
        self._conn = websockets.connect(URL)
        self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()
        self.messages = asyncio.Queue()
        for i in range(1,10):
            await self.messages.put(str(i))
        return self

    async def close(self):
        await self._conn.__aexit__(*sys.exc_info())

    async def send(self):
        while not self.messages.empty():
            await self.websocket.send(await self.messages.get())



    async def receive(self):
        async for message in self.websocket:
            print(message)

            # return await self.websocket.recv()


    async def addmessage(self):

        await self.messages.put('New Hello')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    echo = await EchoWebsocket()
    while echo.websocket.open:
        await echo.send("Hello!")
        await echo.receive()
        await echo.addmessage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

В этом коде есть проблема, которую не могу решить. Он тормозит на моменте `await echo.recieve()`, перестает отправлять что-либо.

WS сервер асинхронный, то есть сообщения клиенту могут приходить не подряд, а отправляться сразу пакетом (10 отправлено, 10 пришло с интервалом полсекунды).
Функция `addmessage` это примитив, который воспроизводит функцию получения сообщения и добавления его в очередь на отправку.
Буду признателен за помощь.